# Animated HTML Canvas background suddenly not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, canvas

So for my personal website, I created an animated background using JavaScript and HTML Canvas.  It worked fine on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. but I recently went to check on it and suddenly the animation isn't working in Chrome.  It actually works in Chrome for mobile, but it doesn't work in Chrome desktop, which makes me think they must have changed something.

To set the background, I use the following code:

```
            <div class="info" style="background:-webkit-canvas(background) repeat;">
            <div class="info-1" style="background:-moz-element(#background) repeat;">
```

(It's been a while since I wrote it, but I think I included both to make it work in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox).

And, in terms of the script, I believe this is the relevant part:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 30);
      };
  })();
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this might have stopped working within the last ~3 months?

Comment: Because it wasn't part of any specs and that it won't go further than this. Don't use experimental features for other things than experiments.

Comment: What specifically wasn't part of any specs?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Canvas-driven-background-images?hl=en